# Define class with Generic Types

Tags: c#

I have the following class definition which works:

```
public class AsyncValidationRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IAsyncRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : IAsyncRequest<TResponse> { }
```

But I need to define TResponse as Envelope where Envelope is:

```
public class Envelope<T> { }
```

I tried the following:

```
public class AsyncValidationRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IAsyncRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : IAsyncRequest<TResponse> 
    where TResponse : Envelope<TModel> { }
```

Basically, I define an Envelope as:

```
ModalA modelA = new ModelA();
Envelope<ModelA> envelopeA = new Envelope<ModelA>();
```

or

```
ModalB modelB = new ModelB();
Envelope<ModelB> envelopeB = new Envelope<ModelB>();
```

And I know my Response is always an Envelope of something ...

But my code does not compile. I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'TModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How to solve this? Do I need an interface?

Comment: what is ``TModel`` here?

Comment: Are you actually missing the left angle bracket in `EnvelopeTModel>` like is showing in your snippet here? What exactly is the message that causes it not to compile?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad TModel is a generic type

Comment: i understand that but you did'nt defined it on class

Comment: @Zack No in my code it has the bracket ... Just added it to my question. The type or namespace name 'TModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to declare `TModel` as a generic parameter, too:

```
public class AsyncValidationRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TModel> : IAsyncRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : IAsyncRequest<TResponse> 
    where TResponse : Envelope<TModel> { }
```